# Spontaneous linguistic evolution

Tags: language, mathematics, conlang

I'm working on some world building, and I am making a conlang for this world. It's intended to be a slightly futuristic language, but with no influence from any existing language (in world) that spontaneously evolved linguistically to meet modern linguistic needs in it's proto-language and evolved from there.
What kinds of needs or linguistic niches that don't usually appear in natural languages would appear here? 
I'd like to have something different with mathematics, but I'm not really sure how mathematics would differ. 
But aside from that I'm not sure what I could imagine being different

Clarification: By "no influences from other languages" I mean that it's nothing like anything seen before, solely because it spontaneously appeared to meet the needs of modern concepts, and it would be artificially evolved from that starting point with a lot of niches that people didn't have when language started out on the plains running from a lion. We don't need to start from "Ah! A lion!" anymore, here we start from modern concepts. 
Clarification tl;dr: it doesn't not have influence, it just didn't start from any existing in world languages at all and thus has different niches

## **Update to my idea to make it more clear exactly what I'm asking**

I'm trying to make a language that is creatio ex nihilo, literally overnight.
The setting is literally the current world, but with some more fictional science (not scifi) aspects, perhaps lattices (See [E8 lattice pseudoscience](https://sapphiremagendavid.blogspot.com/p/the-e8-lattice-and-explicit-name.html)) are more relevant.
I guess a good comparison is the CW's Flash world, their fictional science is sort of what I want to emulate. Perhaps minus the metahumans. 
They actively dramatize the effects of theoretical particles and effects, and what they could do on a macro scale. Often taking a lot of things literally.
After all this is large, and set in motion, and part of reality, a language just shows up over night.

The goal is to have native words for a lot of mechanical, ideological, and mathematical principals which are marginally more advanced and "dramatic" or "emphasized" as described above, that civilization as we (real world) know it.
When I say mathematical, I don't mean that I want it to be math based. I want a different system to how we use base 10 in english, "One, Two, Three, Four, Five..." 
I've been considering the mathematics system used by the language to be 3-Adic, the issue is I have no idea how I'd implement it; Nor how it would differ from plain english math.

I'm not really looking for new words per se, but new functions. Maybe the way these fic-sci tachyons are relevant enough in peoples brains that there's past tense, present tense, future perfect tense, future progressive, and and some kind of case for actual precognition (Future sight).
I'm basically looking for odd reality situations that lead to new language functions, in the three key areas I indicated above.
Perhaps this language, to encompass this idea, could be panmultiversal to reach other realities and therefore need more odd bits and bobs of features.
I'm not trying to really warp anything, more so just fill in gaps that are presently impossible, but in a slightly further in the future fictional science may be prevalent.
So generally I'm looking for ideas that follow along this pattern

Comment: If people think it's too specialized for here, then try [conlang.se], our sister site dedicated to this topic. You should remember to take their tour and read-up in their help center before posting. You're of course welcome here, our [tour] and [help] are at your disposal.

Comment: If it has no influences from existing languages I doubt it can evolve. At most it would be constructed.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I'll check it out and post there if I need to, thanks for pointing me there

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica of course it can evolve - just raise a bunch of children without common language (or even better, not yet speaking ones) together. For a real life relatively well studied example, see the Nicaraguan Sign Language.

Comment: (a) The words "spontaneous" and "evolution" don't belong together in nature. (b) I don't know what "slightly futuristic" means as the only "futuristic" difference between English in 1900 and today is the addition of technical terms. It's almost like you're asking "What would Esperanto look like if it reflected my [completely undefined] world?" (c) A programming language is an example of something that fills a linguistic niche that doesn't appear in natural language. (d) Expressing "I love you" using mathematics would be painful without associated context - it's the context that's magic.

Comment: maybe my question is just really poorly articulated then, I'll come up with a better worded question soon and see if that takes me anywhere better. Thank you for trying to those who tried to help me figure that out

Comment: (1) There is a syntactic ambiguity in the first paragraph: *who* "spontaneously evolved linguistically", the conland or "any existing language"? (2) Languages are notoriously plastic and capable of very fast evolution when such is socially required; as an example, see the current rapid evolution of American towards a dramatic reorganization of its personal pronouns. (3) Languages and concepts exist on different planes; generally, there is no need to change the language in order to denote a new concept -- all you need is a new word. (4) For a mathematically sound *a priori* conlang, try Lojban.

Comment: P.S. [A priori constructed languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language#A_priori_language) are many. In a certain way, some programming languages, such as Lisp, or APL, or Perl, are the most successful such languages.

Comment: @AlexP You make a good point about the pronouns... I guess we need to better understand what the OP means by "evolve." The structure of English isn't changing, it's just the addition of more words, which happens all the time (e.g., technical words). Consequently, I wouldn't claim English is "evolving" at all - but I can see the argument that it is.

Comment: @JBH: My impression (as a foreigner) is that American is evolving towards a language with no personal pronouns in the 3rd person singular applicable to human beings. (Irrespective of what their proponents say, "preferred pronouns" are not pronouns, they are nicknames. By definition, a pronoun replaces a *word*, and has no lexical meaning.) This increases the distance between American and other varieties of English; which is only to be expected for an imperial language spoken of a vast territory : at a certain point in the future we will speak of the English *family* of languages.

Comment: @AlexP OK, I get your point. Yes, that would be an evolution of the structure of the language. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If I were to make a dramatic edit of this post would it be better to just make a new post, or perhaps "strike" ~~out the original content~~ and add the new text?

Comment: What is E8 lattice pseudoscience?

Comment: @Daron There's pseudoscience saying that an E8 Lattice quasicrystal is the source of all 3D reality, and some other odd religious stuff, a place you can read some of it, [here](https://sapphiremagendavid.blogspot.com/p/the-e8-lattice-and-explicit-name.html). But long story short they think it's all powerful proof of god(s)

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking. By and large, *"looking for ideas"* is not what this site is about. I see three questions: do *a priori* conlangs exist? are there languages with a different tense system than English? and can a language have *"mathematical principals"*? (1) *A priori* conlangs do exist. [Lojban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban) is an example; programming languages such as Lisp, APL and Perl might also be considered examples. (2) Yes, the verbal tenses and aspects of English are specifically English. (3) Languages *do not* have "mathematical principals".

Comment: @AlexP I'll close it then

Answer (score 4):

**Your spoken language evolved from written language.**

Our ancestors communicated verbally and languages evolved because of how they were represented verbally.  Over the last couple of hundred years people also used written communication.  Over the past 10 years people communicate a lot by texting.

Some people think English is being affected by texting - people whose primary reading is texting use shorter messages and have a smaller vocabulary.  Some texting terms have come into the language.

https://englishlive.ef.com/blog/english-in-the-real-world/is-text-messaging-ruining-the-english-language/

> Some texting terms have even made it into common parlance: ‘lol’
> (laugh out loud), ‘omg’ (oh my god), pls (please). The craze for
> shortening words, absorbed from texting, is also changing how we speak
> – ‘amaze’ for ‘amazing’, ‘totes’ for totally, ‘blates’ for blatantly:
> these are all largely teenage usages that are becoming mainstream.

In your world the majority of communication is (or until recently was) written, and now written communication is becoming verbal.  It is the reverse of normal language evolution - sort of like the cetaceans returning to the sea.    Noncharacter elements in language (an example from our world are emoticons) are often used in these written communications.  People might borrow characters from Cyrillic or Punjabi for some uses.  When your people speak they have to represent what they would write with their speech.  How do they do it?  New sounds? Gestures?

A trick for the author is how to represent written language as spoken language using a (different) written format.  Good luck!

Comment: I do like this idea, that is a good way to look at the processes that I'm looking to emulate with evolving it. I was definitely looking to go from text to verbal communication like that